# Emacs (Cocoa Emacs) vs Aquamacs for running Clojure on Mac OS X

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, aquamacs, elpa

I used [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) so far, and I need to install and run [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) using [SLIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIME). I googled to get some way to use Clojure on SLIME of Aquamacs, but without success.

## Questions

1. Is it possible to install Clojure on Aquamacs? Or, can you guess why Clojure on Aquamacs doesn't work?
2. Is it normal that Emacs and Aquamacs can't share the same [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/)?
3. Is it possible to use ELPA to install Conjure on Emacs/Aquamacs?
4. I was told that one can use 'lein swank' to run as a server, do you know how to do that?

## Sequences that I tried (and half succeeded)

I tried with [Mac OS X Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/), and by following the steps I could make it work. I mean, I could run Clojure with SLIME.

### Emacs for Mac OS X

Step 1) Install [ESK](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit).

- Git clone and copy all the files into the `.emacs.d` directory
- Add the following code to `.emacs` and relaunch

```
    (when
        (load
         (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/package.el"))
      (package-initialize))
```

Step2) Install using ELPA

- M-x package-list-packages to select packages
- Install

  - clojure-mode, clojure-test-mode
  - slime,  slime-repl
  - swank-clojure
- M-x slime to install the clojure
- Add the following code to `.emacs` and relaunch

```
;; clojure mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/smcho/.emacs.d/elpa/clojure-mode-1.7.1")
(require 'clojure-mode-autoloads)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/smcho/.emacs.d/elpa/clojure-test-mode-1.4")
(require 'clojure-test-mode-autoloads)

;; slime
;(setq inferior-lisp-program "/Users/smcho/bin/clojure")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/smcho/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-20100404")
(require 'slime-autoloads)
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/smcho/.emacs.d/elpa/slime-repl-20100404")
(require 'slime-repl-autoloads)

;; swank-clojure
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/smcho/.emacs.d/elpa/swank-clojure-1.1.0")
(require 'slime-repl-autoloads)
```

### Aquamacs

Now I could use Clojure on Emacs, I tried the same(or very similar) method to run Clojure on Aquamacs once more.

Step 1) Install [ESK for Aquamacs](http://github.com/walter/aquamacs-emacs-starter-kit)

- Copy the files to  ~/Library/Preference/Aquamacs Emacs
- Modify "~/Library/Preferences/Aquamacs Emacs/Preferences.el" to add the following

```
(setq kitfiles-dir (concat (file-name-directory
                    (or (buffer-file-name) load-file-name)) "/aquamacs-emacs-starter-kit"))

; set up our various directories to load
(add-to-list 'load-path kitfiles-dir)  
(require 'init)
```

Step2)
    * Follow the same step as before to install all the (same) packages, but "M-x slime" gives me the following error message. "Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib"

### ELPA

I tried to combine the packages from Emacs and Aquamacs, but they don't combine. I thought I could use the [ELPA](http://tromey.com/elpa/) itself, not from the ESK to make it shared.

The result was not good, as ELPA couldn't download the swank-conjure package.

### Success - Running Aquamacs/Clojure with 'lein swank'.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343555/running-clojure-with-lein-swank-on-aquamacs-problem).

Comment: I have emacs23.2.1 and Aquamacs 2.0 which is based on emacs23.2.1.  I was able to get the package-list-packages work fine on both.  ELPA was able to see that both the emacsen used ERC 5.2 and a few other packages.  If this is what you meant by share the same ELPA, I guess it is possible.

Comment: @vpit3833 : The ELPA is a part of both ESK and ESK for Aquamacs. When I first install some packages with ESK/ELPA, and then launch the Aquamacs, it seems that pacakage.el file is modified so that emacs can't read it. The original (downloaded) ELPA should be shared by both emacs/Aquamacs, but I couldn't test it, as the ELPA itself doesn't work on my machine as I explained.

Comment: I'd recommend putting your "Questions" section up top before you give the description of what you have tried so far. It helps readers to focus on what it is you are actually trying to do rather than try to parse it from your description of steps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquamacs most definitely works with Clojure, since the author of Clojure uses it. However, I use Emacs, and after you perform the steps above in the Emacs section, I recommend checking out labrepl,

http://github.com/relevance/labrepl

If you don't have leiningen, the link to get and install it is in the instructions of the labrepl readme file. I found it extremely helpful when first learning how to set up an environment for Clojure programming. You can take apart the `project.clj` file in labrepl and piece together how it works pretty easily. Not to mention the lessons and training in the built in web application that comes with labrepl.

If you want to use lein swank instead:

Make sure you have leiningen installed. In your project.clj dev dependencies you want to have an entry like this:

```
[leiningen/lein-swank "1.1.0"]
```

http://clojars.org/leiningen/lein-swank

Then after you've done `lein deps` you should be able to run `lein swank` and then from within Emacs run `M-x slime-connect` and just press enter through the defaults.

If you're going to go this route, here is the link directly to leiningen so you can skip the labrepl repository: http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen

Comment: I installed leiningen, and could run 'lein swank'.
With 'M-x slime-connect', I could see the 'user>' prompt, but it doesn't evaluate equation like '(+ 3 4)'. It just doesn't return anything.

Comment: hmm. i didn't have to add any lisp code to my emacs config file when i used ESK. perhaps something you did in there is causing a problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Paul Barry](http://paulbarry.com/articles/2008/07/02/getting-started-with-clojure-and-aquamacs) gives an lecture how to use Aquamacs and Clojure.

It's simple as you can add this code to the `.emacs` file,

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/clojure/clojure-mode")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/Users/smcho/bin/clj")
(require 'clojure-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\.clj\\'" . clojure-mode)
     auto-mode-alist))
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
     (define-key clojure-mode-map "\C-c\C-e" 'lisp-eval-last-sexp)))
```

I could run 'M-x clojure-mode', and C-c C-z for REPL.

And as is asked and answered in *[Running Clojure and other Lisp at the same time on Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340805/running-clojure-and-other-lisp-at-the-same-time-on-emacs)*, I could use both Clojure/Lisp on Aquamacs.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://jaydonnell.com/blog/2011/10/07/setting-up-aquamacs-for-clojure-and-general-goodness/) the easiest setup for the latest version of everything. Here's a quick summary where I"m assuming you have leiningen installed.

Install the swank-clojure plugin

```
$ lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.2
```

Create your clojure project

```
$ lein new test-project
$ cd test-project
$ lein deps
```

Then open one of the clojure files from your project in emacs and run clojure-jack-in

```
M-x clojure-jack-in
```

You are now in a slime buffer with clojure and the dependencies for your project loaded.