# Match Aquamacs' settings in emacs

Tags: emacs, tex, aquamacs, auctex

How can I match Aquamacs' settings in Mac OS X emacs' AucTeX?

Because of some [reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261714/emacs-cocoa-emacs-vs-aquamacs-for-running-clojure-on-mac-os-x) I tried to install AucTeX to emacs for Mac OS X.

For Aquamacs that has pre-installed AucTeX, everything is pretty cool.

1. It runs SKIM pdf viewer for viewing the result.
2. It can use pdfsync for reverse/forward link between Aquamacs and SKIM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following in my `.emacs`, though there are probably better ways:

```
(setq LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1 -shell-escape")
(when (file-exists-p "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline")
  (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
               '("^pdf$" "." "/Applications/Skim.app/Contents/SharedSupport/displayline -b %n %o %b")))
```

You might try seeing what those variables are set to in Aquamacs.  Use `C-h v VARIABLE RET` to see documentation and the current value.