# Running Clojure and other Lisp at the same time on Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, slime

I use [Aquamacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquamacs), and Aquamacs is pre-equipped with [SLIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIME).

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/usr/local/bin/sbcl") #####!!!
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/SLIME/contrib")
(add-to-list 'load-path "/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/SLIME")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

As is asked in somewhere, I try to use Clojure by adding this code.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/clojure/clojure-mode")
(setq inferior-lisp-program "/Users/smcho/bin/clj") ################
(require 'clojure-mode)
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\.clj$ . clojure-mode")
     auto-mode-alist))
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
     (define-key clojure-mode-map "\C-c\C-e" 'lisp-eval-last-sexp)))
)
```

I couldn't make it Clojure run with SLIME, but I'm satisfied with the current setting, the only problem is that because of the `(setq inferior-lisp-program ...)` code, I have to change the `.emacs` code depending on I use Clojure or [SBCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_Bank_Common_Lisp).

Is there any way to solve this problem? Can I choose between multiple (inferior) Lisps?

### Added

I could make Clojure run on Aquamacs. Please refer to *[Running Clojure with 'lein swank' on Aquamacs problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343555)*. Forget about the settings written above, if you want to run Aquamacs/Clojure. You need just one line, `(slime-setup '(slime-repl))` and `lein swank`.

Comment: Added the Lisp tag so that Common Lisp SLIMErs might have a look; I'd expect them to be switching inferior^_superior Lisps much more often than the typical Clojurian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use <kbd>C-u M-x slime</kbd> instead of just <kbd>M-x slime</kbd> to have SLIME ask you for the name of the Lisp executable to be launched, with whatever is your default already filled in.

There's also a `slime-lisp-implementations` variable which I have configured like so:

```
(setq slime-lisp-implementations
      `((clojure ,(swank-clojure-cmd) :init swank-clojure-init)
        (sbcl ("sbcl") :coding-system utf-8-unix)))
```

I have to say that I just can't remember what this does for me anymore (if indeed it does anything)... Type `C-h v slime-lisp-implementations` to learn roughly what it's supposed to do. I seem to have to type `sbcl` if I want to start that, which is fine by me due to the high Clojure-to-SBCL ratio in my SLIME'ing.

*Update:*

I have just rediscovered <kbd>M-- M-x slime</kbd> (that first key is meta-minus for a negative argument), which prompts for one of the names of Lisp implementations in `slime-lisp-implementations` (with tab completion) and then starts the required Lisp. With the above example config, <kbd>M-- M-x slime sbcl</kbd> starts SBCL.

(I find this useful mostly because of how it allows one to configure more complex commands to start Lisp -- e.g. `(sbcl-options ("sbcl" "--an-option" "--another-option") ...)`, `(sbcl-clbuild ("/path/to/clbuild" "lisp") ...)` -- and refer to them by name.)

Comment: By the way, at least the `(clojure ...)` entry is absolutely guaranteed to do nothing at all, since `swank-clojure` currently arranges to have it replaced just before the (Clojure) Swank server is started.