# Running Clojure with 'lein swank' on Aquamacs problem

Tags: emacs, clojure, aquamacs

I installed [leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) and ran lein swank,

1. sudo lein deps
2. lein swank

[Aquamacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquamacs) has everything about [SLIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLIME), so it's OK.

## Solution to this problem

David helped me to be out of trouble.
As Aquamacs has built-in SLIME, I didn't need anything complex about the setup. I just needed one line - (slime-setup '(slime-repl)).

Comment: A couple of things I notice right away: (1) don't use `sudo` for `lein deps` (or any other Leiningen-related commands); (2) do not mix JLine with Emacs. Other than that, could you paste in a complete example of your attempt at interacting with the REPL (from the very start up to at least the "numbers like 1,2,3")? Also, I've written a sort of a meta-tutorial on setting up Clojure with Emacs here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285437/a-gentle-tutorial-to-emacs-swank-paredit-for-clojure/2285756#2285756 -- it's likely to be applicable to Aquamacs as well.

Comment: I elaborated the question. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem if I used (slime-setup '(slime-fancy)).  Changing it to (slime-setup '(slime-repl)) fixed it.

Comment: it's enough to disable on `slime-use-autodoc-mode` with `(setq slime-use-autodoc-mode nil)` before loading `slime-fancy`, all other features will work

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://jaydonnell.com/blog/2011/10/07/setting-up-aquamacs-for-clojure-and-general-goodness/) the easiest setup for the latest version of everything. Here's a quick summary where I"m assuming you have leiningen installed.

Install the swank-clojure plugin

```
$ lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.2
```

Create your clojure project

```
$ lein new test-project
$ cd test-project
$ lein deps
```

Then open one of the clojure files from your project in emacs and run clojure-jack-in

```
M-x clojure-jack-in
```

You are now in a slime buffer with clojure and the dependencies for your project loaded.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You want me to not be lazy, oh ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found that I needed this in my .emacs to get it to work:

```
(eval-after-load "slime"
  '(progn
     (slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-asdf))))
```

Comment: it doesn't work due `slime-fancy` uses `slime-autodoc` that doesn't work with Clojure. See my comment above