# What's the purpose/usage of prefix argument with emacs?

Tags: emacs

As I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340805/running-clojure-and-other-lisp-at-the-same-time-on-emacs), I can choose the lisp for running SLIME with prefix argument(C-u), and I is written in [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecuteExternalCommand), I see that C-u is a way to insert the output in the current buffer.

I use 'C-u 10 SOMETHING', in order to run SOMETHING 10 times.

What's the usage/purpose of using prefix argument (C-u)? Is C-u the only prefix argument?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the [documentation for prefix command arguments](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html).

But, in short, it's a way to interactively provide more information to the command.

- for alpha-numberic keys, generally bound to `'self-insert`, it tells them how many of that character to insert
- for some commands (<kbd>M-x comment-region</kbd>) it means to invert the command, i.e. <kbd>C-u M-x comment-region</kbd> **un**comments the region.
- for some it just tweaks the behavior, <kbd>C-u C-s</kbd> does a `'isearch-forward-regexp` instead of a regular `'isearch-forward`.

So, it all depends on how the command uses the prefix argument.

As far as other "prefix arguments", there are <kbd>C--</kbd>, <kbd>M--</kbd>, <kbd>M-3</kbd> (or any other digit), and some others.

Answer (score 8):

Also bear in mind that C-u as a prefix on its own defaults to passing '(4) as the argument, and each C-u that you insert before the command multiplies this by 4.

Thus you can write a quick way of having a few simply choices that are selected between by using ctrl-u prefixes, for example:

```
(defun insert-date (prefix)
  "Insert the current date. With prefix-argument, use ISO format. With
   two prefix arguments, write out the day and month name."
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((format (cond
                 ((not prefix) "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M %Z" )
                 ((equal prefix '(4)) "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
                 ((equal prefix '(16)) "%d/%m/%Y")
                 ((equal prefix '(64)) "%H:%M:%S")
                 ))
        (system-time-locale "en_GB"))
    (insert (format-time-string format))))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'insert-date)
```

(The above elisp produces a function that inserts a long format date on the key (in this case C-c d), the date + time in short format on C-u C-c d, the short format date on C-u C-u C-c d, and the short format time on C-u C-u C-u C-c d)

You could use this trick to make a 'start-slime' replacement that used clojure by default, but sbcl if you press C-u before the key binding.

Comment: +1 Now I finally understand what's meant by "two prefix arguments" (as seen in e.g. the magit command magit-pull). BTW, Xah Lee wrote about this and other possible `prefix` values at http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_universal_argument.html. For instance, `C-u` `-` without a number makes `prefix` equal to the symbol `-`.

Comment: Note that checking the prefix argument as in this example will cause a surprising inconsistency: a number-less prefix argument like `C-u` to work, but an explicitly-numbered prefix like `C-u 4` will be ignored as if there's no prefix. As I understand it, best practice is to first unwrap the prefix if it's a list: `(when (listp prefix (setq prefix (car prefix))))`. Personally, when only increments of prefix argument are significant like this, I would also consider using `<=` instead of `equal` for comparisons, so that explicit numbered prefixes between the powers of 4 worked intuitively too.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it is that a prefix arg lets you roll two or more different but similar/related commands into one, and put them on similar but related keys.

- Put the most commonly used one on <kbd>KEY</kbd>, for some `KEY`.
- Put another one on <kbd>C-u KEY</kbd>.
- Put another one on <kbd>C-- KEY</kbd>.
- Put another one on <kbd>C-+ KEY</kbd>.

Or put many of them on different numeric prefixes: ..., <kbd>C-u -2 KEY</kbd>, <kbd>C-u -1 KEY</kbd>, <kbd>C-u 0 KEY</kbd>, <kbd>C-u 1 KEY</kbd>, <kbd>C-u 2 KEY</kbd>,...