# What are the good things about slime?

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, slime

As I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261714/emacs-cocoa-emacs-vs-aquamacs-for-running-clojure-on-mac-os-x), I couldn't make it run Aquamacs/slime/clojure, but I could use Auqamacs/clojure with 'M-x conjure-mode', then C-c C-z (run clojure) and C-c C-e (run expression).

I  don't have an experience with SLIME, but I feel that C-c C-z and C-c C-e is just enough for lisp/conjure REPL or debugging.

What features SLIME has more than these features? What people use SLIME for?

Comment: This would make an excellent community wiki post :)

Comment: I suppose you mean clojure-mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, so, *so* much more.

`M-.` to go to a definition.

`C-c C-k` to compile the current buffer.

`M-p` & `M-n` to go forwards and backward in REPL history.

`M-<tab>` for completion.

A debugger. A wonderful REPL.

And **so much more**.

Slime gives so much: [look at its manual](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/).

It shouldn't be too hard to set up: [this post is a great starting point](http://data-sorcery.org/2009/12/20/getting-started/).

Comment: Actually you also get about the same REPL with Clojure-mode using inferior-lisp. And C-c-C-l loads the entire buffer and M-p and M-n give you the history. But I think the debugger and tab completion etc. make using swank worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Tab completion of java class members in addition to clojure functions and such.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what had already been said:

- Highlighting errors, warnings and notes in source code buffers.
- Inspector. An object viewer.
- Paredit. Paredit adds comfort and ease to editing lisp code.
- Macroexpansion.

Comment: Paredit isn't part of SLIME. It can be used in concert with SLIME, but it's not necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's not part of slime; but it fits in nicely.

Comment: You can also use paredit with clojure mode so its not slime specific either.